# A problem with moments of a function

Tags: real-analysis, functions

How to show that there is no continuous function $f:[0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$, that satisfies $\displaystyle \int_0^1 x^nf(x)\,dx = 0$ for all $n = 0,2,3,\cdots$, but $\displaystyle \int_0^1 xf(x)\,dx \neq 0$ ? I will be grateful if the solution involves only theorems of Real-Analysis.

Comment: At least, can I use Weierstrass approximation theorem?

Comment: ya sure .. why not ?:D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In fact, if there exists $n_0\in\Bbb N$, such that  $\int_0^1 x^nf(x)dx=0$ for every $n\ge n_0$, then $f\equiv 0$.

**Proof:** Let $g(x):=x^{n_0}f(x)$, which is continuous on $[0,1]$. Then by Weierstrass approximation theorem, there exists a sequence of polynomials $\{p_n\}$, such that $p_n$ uniformly converges to $g$ on $[0,1]$ as $n\to\infty$.
As a result,

$$\int_0^1(g(x))^2dx=\lim_{n\to \infty}\int_0^1x^{n_0}p_n(x)f(x)dx=0,$$
which implies $g\equiv 0$, and hence $f\equiv 0$.